# doInBackground execution error - Distance-Matrix-API and Places API

Tags: android, json, distance

### MainActivity.java

```
AutoCompleteTextView location, destination;
public Places place1, place2;
Button calculate;
TextView result_a, result_b;
String result_main;
//default values for taxi fare
int basePrice = 10;
double priceMeter = 5.80;
double fare;
int parseFare;
int roundedValue;
String textvalue;
String actual_distance;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    location=(AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.locale);
    location.setAdapter(new PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item));
    location.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            place1 = (Places) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            location.setText(place1.description);
            //location.clearFocus();
            Log.d("AutoCompleteTask", location.getText().toString());
                }
    });

    destination = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.destination);
    destination.setAdapter(new PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item));
    destination.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            place2 = (Places) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            destination.setText(place2.description);
            //destination.clearFocus();
            Log.d("AutoCompleteTask2", destination.getText().toString());
                }
    });



    calculate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.calculate);

    calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new ReadDistanceJSONFeedTask().execute("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins="+location.getText().toString()+"&destinations="+destination.getText().toString()+"&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=driving");
        //result_a.setText("ROUTE A "+result_main +"\n"+ "The estimated fare is Rs."+textvalue);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}


private class ReadDistanceJSONFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{       
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return readJSONFeed(urls[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            try
            {   //Accessing the JSON Results
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

                JSONArray rows = jsonObject.getJSONArray("rows");
                Log.i("json", rows.toString());

                JSONObject obj = rows.getJSONObject(0);

                JSONArray elements = obj.getJSONArray("elements");

                JSONObject ini_dis = elements.getJSONObject(0);

                JSONObject distance = ini_dis.getJSONObject("distance");
                Log.i("json", distance.toString());

                //Distance to send
                actual_distance = distance.getString("text");

                //Calculation part
                String solve = distance.getString("value");
                int parseFare = Integer.parseInt(solve);
                fare = basePrice + ((parseFare/200)*priceMeter);
                roundedValue = (int)Math.round(fare);

                //another activity
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ResultsDisplay.class);
                i.putExtra("Display",actual_distance);
                i.putExtra("Display_b",textvalue);
                startActivity(i);

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.d("ReadDistanceJSONFeedTask", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }

            public String readJSONFeed(String URL){
            //Initial steps to getting the JSON Result
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);
            try
            {
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
                //statusCodes at 200 are OK_Statuses
                if(statusCode==200)
                {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                    String line;
                    while((line=reader.readLine())!=null)
                    {
                        stringBuilder.append(line);

                    }
                    inputStream.close();
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.d("readJSONFeed","Failed to download file");
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.d("readJSONFeed", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
                return stringBuilder.toString();
        }

}
```

I am creating an app that takes in user input of a *location* and *destination* and returns them the **distance between the paths** as well as the **estimated taxi fare**. Also in this program is an auto-complete text-view feature which utilizes the `Google-Places` API.
This application as uses the `Direction-Matrix-API` in which i am currently having problems on the `AsyncTask` ...  The logcat is generating an error on execution in the 'doInBackGround()' method ... please help.

**LogCat Error**

> 03-27 09:29:03.785: I/Choreographer(3468): Skipped 123 frames!  The
>   application may be doing too much work on its main thread. 03-27
>   09:29:05.485: W/dalvikvm(3468): threadid=12: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930) 03-27 09:29:05.525:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3468): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2 03-27
>   09:29:05.525: E/AndroidRuntime(3468): java.lang.RuntimeException: An
>   error occured while executing doInBackground() 03-27 09:29:05.525:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3468):   at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299) 03-27 09:29:05.525:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3468):   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
>   03-27 09:29:05.525: E/AndroidRuntime(3468):   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
>   03-27 09:29:05.525: E/AndroidRuntime(3468):   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239) 03-27
>   09:29:05.525: E/AndroidRuntime(3468):     at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230) 03-27
>   09:29:05.525: E/AndroidRuntime(3468):     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
>   03-27 09:29:05.525: E/AndroidRuntime(3468):   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
>   03-27 09:29:05.525: E/AndroidRuntime(3468):   at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856) 03-27 09:29:05.525:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3468): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Illegal character in query at index 73:
>   http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Lagankhel
>   Rd, Patan, Central Region, Nepal&destinations=Thamel, Kathmandu,
>   Central Region, Nepal&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=driving 03-27
>   09:29:05.525: E/AndroidRuntime(3468):     at
>   java.net.URI.create(URI.java:727) 03-27 09:29:05.525:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3468):   at
>   org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet.(HttpGet.java:75) 03-27
>   09:29:05.525: E/AndroidRuntime(3468):     at
>   com.example.calculator_taxi_fare.MainActivity$ReadDistanceJSONFeedTask.readJSONFeed(MainActivity.java:159)
>   03-27 09:29:05.525: E/AndroidRuntime(3468):   at
>   com.example.calculator_taxi_fare.MainActivity$ReadDistanceJSONFeedTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:111)
>   03-27 09:29:05.525: E/AndroidRuntime(3468):   at
>   com.example.calculator_taxi_fare.MainActivity$ReadDistanceJSONFeedTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
>   03-27 09:29:05.525: E/AndroidRuntime(3468):   at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287) 03-27 09:29:05.525:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3468):   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234) 03-27
>   09:29:05.525: E/AndroidRuntime(3468):     ... 4 more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In here

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new ReadDistanceJSONFeedTask().execute("your url");
        ....
        startActivity(i); //<<<<<

}
```

you are starting next Activity just after executing `ReadDistanceJSONFeedTask` AsyncTask. because AsyncTask execute in separate Thread and control reach to next line without waiting for AsyncTask results .

move Activity start part inside  `onPostExecute` which execute on UI Thread just after when `doInBackground`  execution complete :

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
           ///....your code here..
           // start next Activity here..
           Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ResultsDisplay.class);
           i.putExtra("Display",actual_distance);
           i.putExtra("Display_b",textvalue);
           startActivity(i);
        }
```

**EDIT :**
you also need to use `URLEncoder.encode` before sending parameters for HttpGet

```
String strparams="origins="+location.getText().toString()+"&
                       destinations="+destination.getText().toString()+
                       "&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=driving";
String encodedurl = URLEncoder.encode(strparams,"UTF-8");
new ReadDistanceJSONFeedTask().execute("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps
                                        /api/distancematrix/json?"+encodedurl);
```

Comment: please do refer to the question again

Comment: really sorry to bother you again ... 03-27 11:01:58.996: D/ReadDistanceJSONFeedTask(3989): Index 0 out of range [0..0) ... this popped up and the application seems to be stuck ... i am a beginner on android so i dont know much.

Comment: @holiday11 : ok not an issue just add new log and code with question

Comment: actually this  03-27 11:01:58.996: D/ReadDistanceJSONFeedTask(3989): Index 0 out of range [0..0) popped when applying the URLEncoder.encode ... and the application is there on freeze and no response is there whatsoever.And on checking the result for the http request ... "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED" ...

Comment: @holiday11 : im getting right response when using `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Vancouver+BC|Seattle&destinations=San+Francisco|Victoria+BC&mode=bicycling&language=fr-FR&sensor=false` url without URLEncoder. try it after making ur url same

Comment: Does using the Places AutoComplete feature have any awkward effects ... when I select the AutoComplete text that Google generates errors occur, but when I am using my own input the app works smoothly... Any thoughts on this ?